# Laravel OAuth2 - Password Grant

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, oauth-2.0, lumen

I am trying to build a RESTful API, I am using Lumen and I set up [lucadegasperi's Laravel Oauth2](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/wiki/Implementing-an-Authorization-Server-with-the-Password-Grant) - Password Grant.

In Postman, I am posting 5 parameters:

`grant_type => password`

`client_id => 123`

`client_secret = abc`

`username => testuser`

`password => secret`

And in response, I receive an `access_token` successfully. However, in the end-user scenario, where there are 2 form fields (username and password) only, it doesn't seem logical to place `client_id`, `client_secret` and `grant_type` as hidden fields and post them from there. So should I hard-code these 3 parameters (`grant_type` and valid `client_id` and `client_secret` in the Controller where I validate username and password? It feels wrong too. Where should I put it? What is the optimum way of using it?

This is my `verify()` function:

```
  public function verify($username, $password)
  {
      $credentials = [
      'username'    => $username,
      'password' => $password,
      ];

      if (Auth::once($credentials)) {
          return Auth::user()->id;
      }

      return false;
  }
```